# Using Inner join and sorting records in descending order

Tags: sql

I am working with two tables(`student_class` and `class`) in my database. I have a query below that shows `class` that have `students`. But it is not quite what I am looking for. How to display classes that have students but show the results so maximum seats is descending. Would count be needed?

```
SELECT 
    class.class_name 
FROM 
    class 
INNER JOIN 
    student_class ON class.class_id = student_class.class_id;
```

Tables:

`Student_class`:

```
 CLASS_ID STUDENT_ID
---------- ----------
         2         12
         2         11
         2          2
         7          5
         7          6
         7          7
         7          8
         7          9
         9          2
         9         11
         9         12
        10         20
        10          2
        10          4
```

`Class`:

```
  CLASS_ID CLASS_NAME          TEACHER_ID MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE
---------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Intro to ALGEBRA            11                  12
         2 Basic CALCULUS               2                  10
         3 ABC and 123                  1                  15
         4 Sharing 101                  8                  10
         5 Good Talk, Bad Talk          9                  20
         6 Nap Time                     1                  21
         7 WRITing 101                  5                  10
         8 Finger Painting              9                  14
         9 Physics 230                  2                  20
        10 Gym                          5                  25
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use an order by statement:

```
SELECT class.class_name FROM class INNER JOIN student_class ON class.class_id = student_class.class_id
ORDER BY class.max_seats_available DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You would not need a count. Just do an `ORDER BY MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE DESC`.

```
SELECT class.class_name, class.max_seats_available FROM class INNER JOIN 
student_class ON class.class_id = student_class.class_id ORDER BY 
class.MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE DESC;
```

this might be helped.

Answer (score 1):

If just need to `order by` `MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE` try this:

```
SELECT class.class_name, class.MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE
FROM class
INNER JOIN student_class ON class.class_id = student_class.class_id
ORDER BY class.MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE DESC
```